# APIError(code=-3006): Your borrow amount has exceed maximum borrow amount but I don't

Tags: python, binance, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

```
info = client.get_isolated_margin_account(symbol='BTCUSDT')
totalAssetOfBtc = float(info['totalAssetOfBtc'])
precision = 5
totalBTC = "{:0.0{}f}".format(totalAssetOfBtc, precision)

order = client.create_margin_order(
    symbol='BTCUSDT',
    side=SIDE_SELL,
    type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    sideEffectType="MARGIN_BUY",
    quantity=totalBTC
    )
```

Why am I getting *BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-3006): Your borrow amount has exceed maximum borrow amount* even if I reduce quantity to very small numbers (2% of my totalAssetOfBtc for example)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in abscence of the parameter isIsolated = 'true' so it refers to cross-margin as default which was empty